# JavaScript Get variable content from a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to understand JS, doing it with documentation.

Variable inside/outside a function is quite difficult.

I would like to do a module to execute a code written in multiple areas of my code to finally write it only once :)

```
// GLOBAL VARIABLES
let adherent_type, profil1;

//SOMEWHERE I ASSIGN A VALUE IN ADHERENT_TYPE VARIABLE
adherent_type = "famille";

//THE FUNCTION IN THE MODULE I CREATED IN NODEJS
function profil(adherent_type,profil1) {

    if (adherent_type === "famille") {
        profil1 = "Particulier";
    }

    return profil1;
}

// CALL THE FUNCTION 
carte_adherent.profil(adherent_type,profil1);
```

> The result: **profil1** = **undefined**

Variable **adherent_type** is ok, my issue is on **profil1**.

It is not working when I don't put "profil1" in the () of the function too.

*Thank you very much for your help.*

> UPDATE : this as been resolved by @Telman

> It has been resolved by
> adding "profil1 =" to :
>
> CALL THE FUNCTION
> **profil1 =** carte_adherent.profil(adherent_type,profil1);

Comment: What is `carte_adherent`

Comment: First of all, there are no global variables here, only local variables of wider or narrower scope. Inside `profil`, `profil1` is a parameter, which is just a local variable initialised from the calling argument. It is shadowing the outer variable `profil1`. Assigning to the inner `profil1` inside `profil` thus has no impact on the outer `profil1`. If `profil1` is not a parameter, there will be no shadowing, and `profil1` inside `profil` will refer to the outer scope `profil1`, resulting in `profil1 == "Particulier"`.

Comment: @JaxonCrosmas This is incorrect. The code is equivalent to `let x = 3; function a(x) { x = 7; }; a(x); console.log(x)` (producing `3`, not `7`, because of shadowing). OP's function will never result in anything other than `undefined` in `profil1`, regardless of if the function is called, or what the value of `adherent_type` is.

Comment: @Amadan My bad I misunderstood the question. Yes, you are correct. `profil1` will always be `undefined` in this case. I was stating that the function `profil` is returning the expected value. But I guess OP is stating that they are evaluating `profil1` after the function has completed, not evaluating the result of the `profil` function.

Comment: carte_adherent is the module name I created in nodejs.

Comment: ok thank you understood. Now I get was is shadowed variable because the global and local are fighting

Comment: so in fact I don't have to put the parameter "profil1" in the function

Comment: in fact I would like to use the content of profil1

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a variable to the function, the function creates a copy of it.
So when you change the `profil1` inside the function the value of the `let profil1` is not changed (only the copy is changed).

What you can do is to return the value of `profil` from the function, and then assign the result to the `profil1` variable.

```
function profil(adherent_type) {
    let newProfil;

    if (adherent_type === "famille") {
        newProfil = "Particulier";
    }

    return newProfil;
}

// CALL THE FUNCTION 
profil1 = carte_adherent.profil(adherent_type);
```

The option with `globalThis` probably also will work, in a case you want to make the `profil1` variable global:

```
   function profil(adherent_type) {
        if (adherent_type === "famille") {
            globalThis.profil1 = "Particulier";
        }
    }
    
    // CALL THE FUNCTION 
    carte_adherent.profil(adherent_type);
    console.log(globalThis.profil1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @telman :)
It works. My error was on calling function, I missed the "profil1 =". It was more a logic error ;)

Answer (score 0):

you don't call a function this way in javascript

```
  carte_adherent.profil(adherent_type,profil1);
```

instead this

```
  profil(adherent_type,profil1);
```

now to see your result console it to the machine like this

```
  console.log(profil(adherent_type,profil1));
```

now try it an see the result but first make the changes above

Comment: This isn't necessarily true. `profil` may be a function defined in an object named `carte_adherent`. In this case, the snippet makes sense. But OP has not provided this information.

Comment: Yes it is a nodejs module I create. I thought it was sufficient to tell nodejs module. sorry. As it is a module you put modulename.functionname to call it

Comment: yes I did a console.log and the result is profil1 as the value of "undefined"